# Regex removes whitespace and changes punctuation?

Tags: php, regex

Alright, so this is linked to a previous question I had. I am very new to PHP in general, and simply only need it to fix something someone else did to work for a forum of mine.

This is what I currently have:

```
// Alter post output to create links to user profiles
$post->message = preg_replace(
   '/@ *('.preg_quote($speak['username'], '/').')[:,.]? */i',
'[url=\''.PAGE_URL.RELATIVE_WBB_DIR.'/index.php?'
. 'page=User&userID='.$speak['toID'].'\']@'.$ speak['username'].':[/url]',
                              $post->message);
```

This should change:

```
@JamesNorris, @JamesNorris: @JamesNorris
```

to user profile links, and it does. The only problem is that the other change it makes is this:

```
@JamesNorris:@JamesNorris:@JamesNorris:
```

That is the output from that line given before.
Apparently it is removing the ',' and whitespace, and placing a ':'.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: A really useful tool for assembling and testing regex: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm I'm not 100% on this as I'm learning this too but shouldn't the . be \. since . matches any char (except new line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the `,:.` as its own group and reference that in the replacement:

```
('preg_quote(...)')([:,. ])? */i',
   '[url...'.$speak['username'].'\2[/url]'
```

The `\2` is whatever was captured in the second group (colon, comma, period, space).  It's `\2` because you already have another capture group for the username (that you don't use).

Comment: this worked! Thanks! The only problem I am having now is that it cuts spaces?

Comment: @JNorr44 what does that mean?  It cuts spaces?

Comment: I can't use the @ symbol, because I can't tag that many times, but lets say @ becomes &                        this: &JamesNorris, &JamesNorris:     becomes &JamesNorris,&JamesNorris:

Comment: @JNorr44 I see .. well you don't capture a space after the `,.: ` group either, so if there is a second space there you could either capture it as well and use `\3`, or much more simply, just add a space after `\2 ` in your replace (will people really care if you add a space for them)?

Comment: @JNorr44 - Or, this would be much easier: `('preg_quote(...)')([:,. ])*` (notice the `?` has become a `*` which means it will match zero or more of the characters in the character class, rather than 0 or 1)

Comment: There are 2 problems left, the space afterwards gets cut, and it accepts extra letters after the replacement, such as &JamesNorrisk works, although it ignores the k, and just underlines the &JamesNorris. The ? to * just messes more things up.

Comment: @JNorr44 is it supposed to ignore the k or not?

Comment: It should not ignore it, if it does, then players with longer names could no longer be tagged, because &Jam, is shorter than &JamesNorris, meaning it would ignore the esNorris.

Comment: @JNorr44 that problem has to do with the logic of how you get `speak['username']`